# Automorphism group of an L-function

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory

I define the notion of Galois class of L-functions as follows:

$A$ is a Galois class of L-functions if and only if the following conditions simultaneously hold true:

1) $A$ is a subset of the Selberg class containing the constant function equal to $1$
2) whenever $F$ and $G$ are elements of $A$, then so is $F.G$
3) every element of $A$ factors in a unique fashion as a product of primitive elements of $A$

Then I denote $M$ the maximal Galois class of L-functions (conjecturally equal to the whole Selberg class) and define its group of automorphisms (under composition) $Aut(M)$ as follows:
$\Phi$ is an automorphism of $M$ if and only if the following conditions simultaneously hold true:

1) $\Phi$ is a bijective map from $M$ to itself
2) $\forall F\in M$, $deg(\Phi(F))=deg(F)$, where $deg(F)$ is the degree of $F$ as an element of the Selberg class
3) $\forall (F,G)\in M^{2}$, $\Phi(F.G)=\Phi(F).\Phi(G)$
4) $\Phi$ maps a primitive element of $M$ to a primitive element of $M$

Given an element $F$ of $M$ of degree $d$, one can write $F=\prod_{i=1}^{n}F_{i}^{e_i}$ where $\forall 1\leqslant i\leqslant n$ $F_{i}$ is a primitive element of $M$ and $e_{i}$ is a positive integer. Let's consider the group $G_{F}$ (under composition) of automorphisms of $M$ preserving $F$.
Suppose there exists a Galois extension $\mathbb{K}_{F}$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $d'$ such that $G_{F}$ is either isomorphic to $Gal(\bar{\mathbb{K}}_{F}/\mathbb{K}_{F})$ or to $Gal(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{K}_{F})$.

Is it true that $d=d'$?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT January 4th 2014: Suppose it's true that $d=d'$. Is $Gal(\mathbb{K}_{F}/\mathbb{Q})$ a finite simple group if and only if $F$ is primitive? It would be true for $d=d'=1$ since degree $1$ elements of the Selberg class are exactly the Riemann Zeta function and the Dirichlet L-functions which are known to be primitive. More generally is $Gal(\mathbb{K}_{F}/\mathbb{Q})$ the product of $n$ finite simple groups if and only if $F$ is the product of $n$ primitive elements of the Selberg class?